# Archivo no encontrado mediante require

Tags: php

Estoy iniciando en el mundo de PHP y en estos momentos estoy queriendo comenzar utilizando el modelo MVC. Para el efecto, quiero "llamar" un archivo a modo de prueba a través de su URL, pero
por más que hago modificaciones, el sistema no encuentra el archivo al que quiero llamar.

El árbol de carpetas está de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente quiero llamar al archivo "include.php" mediante index.php

include.php

```
<?php  

    echo 'Se ha incluido el archivo';
    
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php  

    require "require/include.php";
    
?>
```

Se trata de algo simple, pero por mas modificaciones que haga, tengo siempre el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los elementos de php.ini están activos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `../require/include.php` prueba así

Comment: No te funciona por que al momento ese **`require`** esta buscando en la misma carpeta donde existe index.php, debes *salir* de esa carpeta y posterior ingresar a la ruta donde esta el archivo que buscas

Comment: Funciona... Gracias